# Get rid of blank entry in select tag

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, select

I have a number of items that get their data from a Json object and populate it using angular.

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.cargoList">
    <option ng-repeat="cargo in MyCtrl.cargoList">{{ cargo.name }}</option>
</select>
```

And whenever I load the form, I get something like this in my console:

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.cargoList">
    <option value="? object:25 "?></option>
    <option value="">Gloves</option>
    <option value="">Jacket</option>
    <option value="">Shoes</option>
</select>
```

I can get the values to appear just fine, but I can't seem to get rid of the very first option. I don't mind the select box showing the very first element in the list, but I don't want it to be a blank line. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat

Comment: Didn't work. I got the exact same problem as this guy:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488181/angularjs-extra-blank-option-added-using-ng-repeat-in-select-tag

Comment: You can init the ng-repeat, but again, you should use ng-options instead, see answers below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select 1st option by default on `ng-init="MyCtrl.selectedCargo=MyCtrl.cargoList[0].name"` & `ng-model` name should not be same as that of your `cargoList`.

**Markup**

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.selectedCargo" ng-init="MyCtrl.selectedCargo=MyCtrl.cargoList[0].name">
    <option ng-repeat="cargo in MyCtrl.cargoList" value="cargo.name">{{ cargo.name }}</option>
</select>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FVGvFK4qDL431LRsP4Dk?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure how, but your solution worked. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-options instead of ng-repeat

```
 <select ng-model="MyCtrl.selectedListItem" ng-options="cargo for cargo in MyCtrl.cargoList"></select>
```

You can fine tune the labels/values further if you like, check the documentation here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

You can ng-init, or set the first value to defualt, something like

```
MyCtrl.selectedListItem = MyCtrl.cargoList[0]
```

So if you want a function to detect you have changed the value of the select you would use ng-change like so :

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.selectedListItem" ng-options="cargo for cargo in MyCtrl.cargoList" ng-change="selectChanged"></select>
```

In your controller

```
$scope.selectChanged = function(){
 //apply your logic
};
```

Comment: For those down voting, how may i improve this?

Comment: Not downvoter but re-read `MyCtrl.cargoList = MyCtrl.cargoList[0]`

Comment: @ajmajmajma I'm downvoter. you have same `ng-model` as that of `MyCtrl.cargoList`

Comment: Suppose I needed an ng-click for each option. How do I do it, then?

Comment: @MilesPeterson why would you use an ng-click? Typically you would just use ng-change on the select itself. ng-change would fire whatever function you linked it to when you changed the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngOption](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) `<option>`

> The `ngOptions` attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of `<option>` elements for the `<select>` element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the `ngOptions` comprehension expression.

I have used following expression

> label for value in array

*HTML*

```
<select ng-model="MyCtrl.cargo" ng-options="cargo.name for cargo in MyCtrl.cargoList">
</select>
```

and In your controller set model value as first element of list

```
this.cargo = this.cargoList[0]
```

Also note: You can use `MyCtrl.cargoList` as model as well as array So you should use another variable to hold the model value.